# Issues with UITextView input in regards to spaces and backspacing

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

This is my current setup that I am encountering the problem:

1. There is a `UITextView`. The user types in his/her search terms.
2. These search terms are allocated in the form of a string. This
   string incorporates the search terms into a URL. This updates as the user types.
3. The string is displayed in a `UILabel` on the user's screen. This updates as the user types.

These are the issues I am facing:

1. When the user backspaces all characters, the first character never goes away on the `UILabel` until new characters are typed.
2. I have attempted to set restrictions to prevent a user from beginning their input with a space. However, these do not work.
3. I have attempted to set restrictions to prevent a user from entering more than one space. However, the application is allowing a maximum of two spaces.

This is my code with some explanation of what is going on.

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string; {


    // unformatted verson of the original string (user input from the UITextView, 'keywords' is inserted into the URL
    NSString *original = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.com/?q=%@%@", self.keywords.text,string];

    // creates the formatted version of the string by replacing certain characters with others as lmgtfy was designed

    NSString *formatted = original;
                formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
                formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]; 




    // displays the formatted version of the string, which is now actually a URL
    self.link.text = formatted;


    // removing whitespace at various locations to prevent misformatting of the string
    // instance i: forbidding more than one space between search terms
    // instance ii: forbidding a space to start the search terms

    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespace].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        whitespaceCount++;
        if (whitespaceCount > 1)
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        whitespaceCount = 0;
        return YES;
    }

    if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;




    return YES; }
```

Any solution to these three problems would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using UITextView or UITextField ? Because the method in your code is a delegate method of UITextField.What is that self.keywords ? Is it a UITextView.And self.link is a UILabel.

Comment: @NimishaPatel Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am modified your code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if(textField == self.keywords)
   {
      //prevents user to begin their input with space
      if(textField.text.length == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@" "])
      {
         return NO;
      }
      //Not allow the user to enter multiple space
      char space = [textField.text characterAtIndex:textField.text.length-1];

    if([string isEqualToString:@" "] && (space == ' '))
    {
        return NO;
    }

      NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];

      if([string isEqualToString:@""])
      {
         //If user press the backspace.Remove the last character.
         [newString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(newString.length-1, 1)];
      }
     else
     {
         [newString appendString:string];
     }

  // unformatted verson of the original string
    NSString *original = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://.com/?q=%@",newString];

    NSString *formatted = original;
    formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
    formatted = [formatted stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    self.link.text = formatted;
}

return YES;
}
```

To convert a string to url there is lots of method.
You can also try this method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.

Comment: Good start, but there are a few requirements that have been taken away by this implementation. Firstly, the user must only be able to enter a maximum of one space between words. Secondly, I require a special way of encoding the URL: by replacing all ' ' with '+' and all '+' with '%2B' (these are not to override each other)

Comment: I have submitted a minor edit, this makes your code work (changed to `self.link.text = formatted;`). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction.If this code help you, then you can accept the answer or upvoted it.:-)